# Selecting a Field With a String Name Only

Tags: python, django

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class WeekOne(models.Model):
    # Required benchmarks for given exercises
    squatBenchmark = 1000
    lungeBenchmark = 250
    stairDaysCountBenchmark = 3

    totalGoals = 4

    squats = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    lunges = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    skipStairs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stairDaysCount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    # Running count of benchmarks met.
    completeCount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    # Set to true if benchmarks reached. 
    weekOneComplete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to access the field 'squats', i.e., in a variable assignment `amount = user.week_one.squats`, but because of the way the views and templates work, I don't have access to a reference to the squats field, I only have a string `squats`. Is there any way to use this string to access that field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) is for:

```
amount = getattr(user.week_one, 'squats')
```